# an unhandled exception occurred in w3wp.exe windwos server 2013 iis

Tags: c#, server, iis-7, windows-server-2016

[image]

This problem appears with me on the client's server when I run my site and it appears on a daily basis, but at different periods
I'm tired of searching for a solution and haven't found a solution yet

Knowing that it does not appear on other servers, only a specific server encountered the problem

Comment: Check the event viewer logs in such case, you will get some information

Comment: I watched the  event viewer logs and did not reach the solution after I tried many solutions and I did not know what was the reason

Comment: Just verify the .net framework version on server. But there can be multiple reasons, it’s very hard to tell with the given information

Comment: The strange thing is that this version is present on more than one server with different clients, and this message only appears here

Comment: Check application logs do you see in exceptions. You need to add more logs to get information about exception

Comment: 1. It only appears on this machine because VS is installed and wants to debug unhandled exceptions. On other machines without VS installed, you should observe similar exceptions in Windows event log. 2. Since the exception is caught by VS, simply debug it and learn more about the exception itself.

Comment: You can use debug diag to get dump file. It will show you the detailed error message. You can download it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210).